# Sticky footer with purecss

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I want to achieve a sticky footer so the footer is at the bottom of the window even if the page content is short, but will be pushed down on pages with longer content ([like this](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)).

I am using YUI purecss on the page, but the pure-g div in the header does not expand to the full width like it normally does.

HTML

```
<body class="site">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-4">One quarter</div>
            <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-3-4">Three quarters</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1" style="background-color:#302c2d; color:white;">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.site {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    margin:0;
}
.main {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
    margin:0px auto;
    max-width:600px;
}
.header {
    max-width:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fstkxbw8/2/)

Is there some additional css I need to add or a better way to achieve the sticky footer while still being able to use purecss modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header div just needed a width set to 100% to stop it collapsing.

```
.header {
    max-width:600px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So YUI purecss works no problem inside the sticky footer template.